# Label "labelname" is not defined

Tags: label, 8085

Currently trying to make a program that bubble sorts several numbers either in ascending or descending order, where type of order is decided by the CV in 00h. So, i just can't pinpoint what's the reason for this problem, because when i try to compile the code it says:"Label STARTASC is not defined. Also check the label definition, there may be some issues on that line." Here is code:

```
mvi H,00
MOV A, M    ; Load control value into accumulator
CPI 00H     ; Compare with 00
JZ STARTDESC  ; If equal, jump to descending sort
JMP STARTASC  ; Otherwise, jump to ascending sort

STARTDESC:  LXI H, 2500H    ;Load the size of the array(number)
MVI B, 00H      ;Set register B to zero
MOV C, M        ;Set register C to the number of array's elements
DCR C           ;Decrease C
INX H           ;Increment the pointer to access the array's element
CHECKDESC:  
MOV A, M        ;Store array's elements in ACC
INX H           ;Increment the pointer to access the next array's element
CMP M           ;Compares ACC with the next element
JNC NEXTDESC    ;Jumps to NEXTDESC if ACC value is less
MOV D, M        ;Swaps the elements that were being compared
MOV M, A        ;...
DCX H           
MOV M, D        ;...
INX H    
MVI B, 01H      ;Stores 1 in register B, if the swap is made
NEXTDESC:   
DCR C           ;Decrement register C for the next iteration
JNZ CHECKDESC   ;If c>0, then jumps to CHECKDESC
MOV A, B        ;Moves contents of register B to the ACC
CPI 01H         ;Compares ACC with 01H(1)
JZ STARTDESC    ;If B=1, then jumps to the start of the loop
HLT             ;If not, then the sorting is done and program stops

STARTASC:  LXI H, 2500H    ;Load the size of the array(number)
MVI B, 00H      ;Set register B to zero
MOV C, M        ;Set register C to the number of array's elements
DCR C           ;Decrease C
INX H           ;Increment the pointer to access the array's element
CHECKASC:   
MOV A, M        ;Store array's elements in ACC
INX H           ;Increment memory to access next element
CMP M           ;Compares ACC with next element
JC NEXTASC      ;Jump to NEXTASC, if ACC value is less then 
JZ NEXTASC      ;or Jump to NEXTASC, if ACC value is equal
MOV D, M        ;Swaps the elements that were being compared
MOV M, A        ;...
DCX H           
MOV M, D        ;...
INX H    
MVI B, 01H      ;Stores 1 in register B, if the swap is made
NEXTASC:    
DCR C           ;Decrement register C for the next iteration
JNZ CHECKASC    ;If c>0, then jumps to CHECKDESC
MOV A, B        ;Moves contents of register B to the ACC
CPI 01H         ;Compares ACC with 01H(1)
JZ STARTASC     ;If B=1, then jumps to the start of the loop
HLT             ;If not, then the sorting is done and program stops
```

So just want to know why is this happening.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a platform issue. Some platforms, such as [this online simulator](https://www.sim8085.com/), do not correctly parse labels on empty lines. Thus, it now compiles smoothly by simply changing the following:

```
CHECKDESC:  
MOV A, M
```

to

```
CHECKDESC:  MOV A, M
```